# Удаление пробелов в начале строки

Tags: kotlin, list

Новичок в котлине, можете подсказать, как избавиться от пустого места в каждом элементе в начале?

[image: ов]

Comment: Например, в данном случае это нужно сделать с Михайловым и Фомином

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишу с утюга, проверить код не могу, но примерно так:

```
for (index in results.indices) {
    results[index] = results[index].trim(' ')
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)